How can I use a mobile broadband stick with a VoIP server to route calls to multiple devices over Wi-Fi and VPN?
How can I manage incoming and outgoing calls directly via a VoIP server with a compatible 5G/4G/3G stick?
I want to use a SIM card that offers a flat rate for calls in Europe. The idea is to use it with multiple devices on Wi-Fi and via VPN with a VoIP client.
I also want to share the Internet connection via the hotspot function (WLAN/USB). It's okay if the connection drops during a call.
I have been looking for a solution for 2 years. Is there any hardware, e.g. an AVM Fritzbox, that redirects mobile calls from a 5G/4G stick to DECT? I haven't found anything suitable so far.

When you say "flat rate" do you mean all inclusive of your monthly fee, or a simple per-minute/per-call rate regardless of where in Europe you are? Last time I looked the Betamax/Finearea family of clones offered pretty good VoIP rates across UK/EU. But that unbundles your telephony from your Internet connection - is that what you want? (Mind, all of these is surely OT for U&L?)

So the immediate reaction I have to this is: that's a bit backwards. Use a VoIP provider that offers you the same flatrate, immediately solving your problem.
Assuming you literally can't do that, or for whatever other reason really need to route calls via cellular technologies: It's going to be more complicated.  You'll need to set up a PBX software (for example, asterisk), sort out which hardware driver interface you need for the cellular dongle (for example, asterisk-chan-dongle), buy that dongle, set up/configure and operate your PBX.

Is there any hardware, e.g. an AVM Fritzbox, that redirects mobile calls from a 5G/4G stick to DECT?

This will not work on a Fritz!Box, you'll need a separate server (could be something like an Atom server, orangePi, whatever somewhat capable Linux box you have at hand).
You can of course buy PBX hardware, which contains cellular fallback, but these things typically come enterprise-priced.
Considering neither the dongle, nor the server, nor the electricity to run both, will be free, I'd really financially re-evaluate the VoIP account option, seriously. Note that even 5G goes that route, if possible: It allows your phone to make VoIP calls by default using your cellular identity, no matter whether your connecting via cellular radio interface, or some Wifi. In other words, not even your smartphone is necessarily still doing what you want to achieve, and prefers to just directly go for the VoIP approach. That's kind of logical – phone calls in 4G/5G are packetized data, anyways, and while the packets don't necessarily travel the same route as internet data does, that's of little concern to the phone (aside from knowing whom to tag as receiver of that data).
